# Anyway to send Custom Method by using Java HttpClient

Tags: java, rest, apache-httpclient-4.x

We are currently using HttpClient 4.3 for all REST communications with other service providers, however, one of our recent providers has some custom methods sitting within the API.

I was trying to figure out a way to send custom methods (Methods not in standard such as GET, POST, PUT, etc.).

Anyone has similar experience before by using HttpClient?
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest that you use the `RequestBuilder` class ([javadoc](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/RequestBuilder.html)) to construct the `Request` objects.  The static `RequestBuilder.create` method allows you to specify any "method" String for your request object.

Answer (score 2):

Implement `FOO` method by extending HttpRequestBase as follows:

```
public class HttpFoo extends HttpRequestBase{

    public final static String METHOD_NAME = "FOO";

    public HttpFoo() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public String getMethod() {
        return METHOD_NAME;  
    }

    public HttpFoo(final String uri) {
        super();
        setURI(URI.create(uri));
    }

    public String getName() {
        return "FOO";
    }
}
```

And then the above method can be used just like any other existing methods like GET(HttpGet) etc.

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpFoo fooMethod = new HttpFoo(fooUrl);        
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(fooMethod);
```

Have tested with

```
  <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
  <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
  <version>4.5.2</version>
```